# Why does an <input type='button'> wrapped in an <a> tag not work in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This code works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but is failing for me on (Windows) IE 8:

```
<a href='http://google.com'>
   <input type="button" name='go' value='go'>
</a>
```

Why? And should I just use a (clumsy) onClick event to get around it?

Grrrrr....

Comment: Did you try `<a href='http://google.com'><button>go</button></a>` ?

Comment: Just tried it-- same thing: works in Chrome, doesn't work in IE 8 :-(

Comment: What is your motivation for having a `button` inside of an `a`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a `<button>` inside an `<a>` element.

You can add some CSS to the `<a>` to look like a button however.

Or get around it like:

```
<input type="button" value="Google" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'http://google.com';" />
```

Comment: +1 That's not valid HTML "The element input must not appear as a descendant of the a element." [validators](http://validator.nu/) are your friend

Comment: `javascript:` isn't necessary -- it's javascript inside `onClick`, not a url

Comment: The "getting around it" is a bad solution anyway; it won't go anywhere for people without JavaScript. Much better to just style the link.

Comment: Thanks. If you have Javascript turned off when you visit my site, you will have bigger problems than this particular button not working :-)

Comment: this fixed it for me, works in IE9 now.  As the Eric said, you have to have javascript on for our site to work at all.