# Javascript alert click to delete not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a JavaScript, when I click on delete, it pops up for confirmation, before I can delete, it works very well in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. But when I click on delete in IE8 it pops up shows the confirmation and when a file is deleted, it refuse to delete. does anyone has a work around for that? here is my snippet below

**Trigger**

```
<?php echo '<td><a href="delete.php?staff_id=' . $row['staff_id'] . '"><input type="button" onclick="confirmDelete(event)" value="delete"></a></td>'; ?></td>
```

**Delete confirmation snippet**

```
function confirmDelete(e) {
 if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Record?'))
   alert('Record Deleted !');
 else {
  alert('Cancelled !');
  e.preventDefault();
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't put a button inside an `<a>` tag. Just style the `<a>` tag to look like a button. You don't need two elements for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think IE 8 doesn't like your <input> tag inside of the link. You can add the onclick handler to the "<a>"-tag:

```
<?php echo '<td><a href="delete.php?staff_id=' . $row['staff_id'] . '" onclick="confirmDelete(event)">Delete</a></td>'; ?>
```

BTW: you have two "</td>"s, one outside of the php-block.

**EDIT**

A second thought: As the delete action changes the state of your application, it is good practice to "POST" the data. So a better approach is:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post" onsubmit="confirmDelete(event)">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="staff_id" value="<?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
</div>
</form>
```

In PHP you can access the staff_id via $_POST['staff_id'].

**EDIT 2:**

Updated javascript, both approaches (link and button):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function confirmDelete() {
    if (!confirm('Delete?')) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Version 1 (link)</h1>
    <div>
        <a href="delete.php?staff_id=1" onclick="return confirmDelete()">Delete</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Version 2 (button)</h1>
    <form action="delete.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirmDelete()">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="staff_id" value="<?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested in IE 7-10 & FF.

Regards,

Comment: Yep - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730431/why-does-an-input-type-button-wrapped-in-an-a-tag-not-work-in-ie

Comment: It works you are right  IE 8 doesn't like your <input> tag inside of the link. thanks you saved me lots of stress

Comment: Its still having issues in IE8 when it alarts you to delete and you click n cancel it still goes ahead and delete, but it is working well in FF and google crome

Comment: Add "return false;" to your Javascript code, right after "e.preventDefault();". This should help.

Comment: When return false; is added after e.preventDefault() it deletes but refuse to popup a confirmation

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry, I didn't test your javascript in a html page. I've checked now and updated my answer. Please try the new version. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

That happens because FF and IE bubble the click event differently.

The problem is that you button is inside the  tag, which has it's own click handler.

You should try something like this:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=1" onclick="confirmDelete(event)">delete</a>
```

or even simplier:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">delete</a>
```

That will work the same way in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the two times confirm message when we delete the anythings from the database. Here is the code

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var cont = false;
    cont = confirm('Warning! Delete this membership level?')
    if (!cont) {
        return false;
    }
    cont = confirm('Last Warning! Are you really sure?\nDeleting this membership level cannot be undone!');
    if (!cont) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

<a href="action=delete_level&id=<?php echo $member_level; ?>" onclick="return confirmDelete()">Delete</a>
```

Thanks..